# perl how to split string from array and save it back

Tags: arrays, perl

I've tried to split string from array and save it back with perl, but it's can't split well.
I've store a data to an array @nameInt.
Data:

```
ge-1/1/2.552
ge-1/1/2.561
ge-1/1/2.562
ge-1/1/2.580
ge-1/1/2.582
ge-1/1/2.590
ge-1/1/2.592
ge-1/1/2.640
ge-1/1/2.642
ge-1/1/2.644
ge-1/1/2.650
```

code:

```
foreach my $interface(@nameInt){
    @sepInt = split /[.]/, $interface;
}
```

I tried to split and save into new array (@sepInt), but when I tried to print out, it's shows and error

```
print "name interface: ".$sepInt[0][0]." | vlan id: ".$sepInt[0][1];
    Can't use string ("ge-1/1/5") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use
```

expected:

```
name interface: ge-1/1/2 | vlan id: 552
name interface: ge-1/1/2 | vlan id: 561
name interface: ge-1/1/2 | vlan id: 562
...
so on
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as you're creating an array, not an array of arrays, I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
my @array = qw (ge-1/1/2.552 ge-1/1/2.561 ge-1/1/2.562 ge-1/1/2.580 ge-1/1/2.582 ge-1/1/2.590 ge-1/1/2.592 ge-1/1/2.640 ge-1/1/2.642 ge-1/1/2.644 ge-1/1/2.650);

foreach (@array){
    my @sepInt = split(/[.]/);
    print "name interface: $sepInt[0] | vlan id: .$sepInt[1]\n"
}
```

Outputs:

```
name interface: ge-1/1/2 | vlan id: .552
name interface: ge-1/1/2 | vlan id: .561
name interface: ge-1/1/2 | vlan id: .562
name interface: ge-1/1/2 | vlan id: .580
name interface: ge-1/1/2 | vlan id: .582
name interface: ge-1/1/2 | vlan id: .590
name interface: ge-1/1/2 | vlan id: .592
name interface: ge-1/1/2 | vlan id: .640
name interface: ge-1/1/2 | vlan id: .642
name interface: ge-1/1/2 | vlan id: .644
name interface: ge-1/1/2 | vlan id: .650
```

Comment: thank you friend, if it's null, like ge-1/1/2 without ".", i got error message "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string ". Is it because I use strict?

Comment: It's because you're truing to print something that's not there. If there's no `.` in your element, then there can't be a `$sepInt[0]` and `$sepInt[1]`

Comment: how do we change uninitialized value to others? if there's no `.` in the element?

Comment: @rabka After splitting the string into `@sepInt`, you can do `$sepInt[1] ||= "none"` to make sure that there's a valid string value there.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to higher-order functions in Perl!

```
map {split /[.]/, $_} @nameInt
```

The built-in function `map` helps you to get above the trees so you can see the forest. In other words, it helps you focus your attention on what you want to do rather than on intermediate bookkeeping values such as your `$interface` and `@sepInt`.

...and, hmm, perhaps what you want is a list of pairs of elements.

```
map {[split /[.]/, $_]} @nameInt
```

Comment: I'm guessing you meant something like `@sepInt = map { [ split /[.]/, $_ ] } @nameInt;`?

Comment: @ysth Yes, I meant that.

Comment: @ajm475du : if we got null or undefined value, how do we alter it to other string?

Answer (score 2):

Use an array of array:

```
foreach my $interface(@nameInt){
    push @sepInt, [ split /[.]/, $interface ];
}
```

Comment: `push @sepInt, [ split /[.]/, $interface ];` ... yes?

Comment: I've tried it, and still error Can't use string ("ge-1/0/0") when I print $sepInt[0][0].

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration of this loop:

```
foreach my $interface(@nameInt){
    @sepInt = split /[.]/, $interface;
}
```

you replace `@sepInt` with the newly split line. `@sepInt` is always an array of strings. So when you get to

```
print "name interface: ".$sepInt[0][0]." | vlan id: ".$sepInt[0][1];
    Can't use string ("ge-1/1/5") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use
```

`$sepInt[0]` is a string, not an array.

Did you mean to use `$nameInt[0][0]` there?

Comment: I'm not saying it would have worked, I'm just trying to get clarity on what he was trying to do :-)